# отобразить любой текст при выборе пункта в listview c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Когда нажал на пункт в listbox, то показывается текст в textbox1,
например, нажал на пункт 12 (listbox.item.add("12")); и в textbox появился текст textbox1.text="asdasdasd"
если нажал на другой пункт то появилось другой текст в textbox1
не знаю как сделать..

Comment: winforms или wpf?

Comment: @S.Kost winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У компонента **ListBox** есть событие **SelectedIndexChanged**, в обработчике которого можно реализовать нужную вам логику. Например, так:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Объявляем переменную lb и приводим компонент, вызвавший событие к типу ListBox
        //(у нас же событие сгененрировал ListBox1, верно? А он имеет тип ListBox.
        var lb = sender as ListBox;
        //В наж текст-бокс пишем номер выбранного пункта, здесь lb.SelectedIndex + 1 так как
        //нумерация с нуля.
        textBox1.Text = "Выбран пункт №" + (lb.SelectedIndex + 1).ToString();
    }
```

или так:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Получим номер выбранного пункта:
        int i = (sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex + 1;
        //В зависимости от номера делаем какие-то РАЗНЫЕ действия:
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                textBox1.Text = "Выбран первый пункт списка";
                break;
            case 2:
                textBox1.Text = "Тра-ля-ля";
                break;
            case 3:
                textBox1.Text = "Тру-ля-ля";
                break;
            case 4:
            case 5:
                textBox1.Text = "Выбран 4 или 5 пункт, лениво уточнять...";
                break;
            default:
                textBox1.Text = "Я таких цифр не знаю!";
                break;
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Можно для привязки объявить и заполнить массив связанных с каждым пунктом значений. В примере я объявляю строковый массив (хотя он может быть любого типа) из 5 пунктов, и, в зависимости от индекса выбранного пункта в `ListBox`, вывожу соответствующий этому индексу элемент массива.
Если у вас в `ListBox` будет 100 пунктов, то и массив должен быть не менее чем из 100 пунктов.
Но на всякий случай делаю проверку индекса:

```
    public string[] textData = new string[5] { "qwe", "rty", "uio", "p[]", "asd" };

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Получим индекс выбранного пункта:
        int i = (sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex;
        //Проверяем, не вышли ли мы за границы масива?
        if (i > textData.GetLength(0)-1)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "С этим пунктом ничего не связано!";
            return;
        }
        textBox1.Text = textData[i];
    }
```

Comment: не то что мне надо, я могу ввыбрать любой пункт из списка и в textbox должно отображатся  именна та строка которая "привязана" к тому пункту

Comment: А как именно строка у вас привязана? Ведь в указанном мной примере в зависимости от выбранного пункта можно определить другую логику, которая будет учитывать как раз тот механизм привязки, который есть у вас.

Comment: к первому пункту привязан (как пример) слово "qwe",
к второму пункту привязан (как пример) слово "rty",
к третьему пункту привязан (как пример) слово "uio",
к четвертому пункту привязан (как пример) слово "pasd"
примерно так

Comment: Я понимаю о чем вы, и спрашивал как именно в коде у вас реализована привязка такая. Чрез массив, например, возможно, или еще как?

Comment: Обновил и дополнил ответ, сделав привязку через массив.

Comment: Норма, как написать такое условие ?
Если нажал первый элемент в listbox то в textbox такая та строка, если второй элемент выбран то в textbox такая то другая уже строка

Comment: Так вот код выше уже дан, после слова UPDATE. Там когда нажимается первая строка, то выводится "qwe", для второй - "rty", для третьей - "uio", для четвертой - "p[]", и для пятой - "asd".

Comment: работает на отлично но код ДО UPDATE

Comment: На самом деле работает любой из приведенных кодов (перед тем как писать, я же проверял в проекте), разница между ними лишь в деталях реализации. Принцип один и тот же - при выборе в ListBox любого пункта, получаем его числовой индекс. Далее уже на основании этого номера тем или иным способом решаем что и как выводить в текст-бокс.